# How to redirect output in a task in nimble

Tags: nim-lang, nimble-nim

If I have this task in a nimble file:

```
task readme, "generate README.md":
  exec "nim c -r readme.nim > README.md"
```

with this `readme.nim`:

```
echo "# Hello\nworld"
```

executing task with nimble (`nimble readme`) does not redirect the output of readme.nim to file.
As expected running `nim c -r readme.nim > README.md` from terminal correctly creates/updates `README.md`.

Is this intended behaviour of nimble? is there a workaround?

**note**: the above was tested on windows.

Comment: note that nimble tag, besides being very little used (29 questions including this one currently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nimble) has been used with a lot different meanings (grails plugin, R package, a CRM, ...). Not sure what should be done there (edit tag info? ask for removal (how)?)

Comment: Regarding the tag: users with more than 1.5K points can create new tags. What would you suggest here? nimble-manager? nimble-package?

Comment: probably nimble-nim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to answer by @xbello and ensuing discussion, I found a good workaround for my use case:

```
task readme, "generate README.md":
  exec "nim c readme.nim"
  "README.md".writeFile(staticExec("readme"))
```

the explanation to why the simple `exec` has to do with the fact that nimble uses [nimscript.exec](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimscript.html#exec%2Cstring) which internally uses `rawExec` which is a builtin that (judging from different behaviours reported here for windows and linux) is not entirely cross-platform when it regards output pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I end up with the expected README.md:

```
$ cat README.md
# Hello
world
```

But sometimes (the `readme.nim` has to be compiled or recompiled) I end up with something like this:

```
CC: readme.nim
# Hello
world
```

That is, the full stdout (not the stderr) of the `nim c -r readme.nim` command, as expected. As a workaround you could encapsulate what you want to do in the `readme.nim`:

```
import os

let f: File = open(commandLineParams()[0], fmWrite)
f.write "# Hello\nworld"
f.close()
```

And in your nimble file:

```
task readme, "generate README.md":         
  exec "nim c -r readme.nim README.md"
```

---

Another workaround could be to suppress the output of `nim c`:

```
task readme, "generate README.md":
  exec "nim c --verbosity:0 -r readme.nim > README.md"
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the above was tested on windows, I will add that. I guess this is on linux, right?

Comment: Yes, it is on Linux.

Comment: ok, thanks. the above is useful to know. the workaround, while a sensible way of doing that, would not work for my use case where I do not want to change the readme.nim (in particular the workaround requires to change all echo appearing in the file). I was hoping for a workaround in the nimble file.

Comment: also the fact that sometimes you have a different output tells me that something is happening with exec command in nimble that I do not understand and I would like to (besides not being cross platform). mmh, maybe I should open an issue in nimble...

Comment: Nimble uses nimscript.exec, that just executes a command without capturing any output. It just knows if all went OK (exit 0) or something failed. Again: when you capture the output of "nim c -r script.nim", that captures the output of both executions "nim c" and "script". So I guess another workaroud would be "nim -c --verbosity:0 -r readme.nim > README.md"

Comment: ok, now looking at nimscript.exec I was able to reach system.staticExec and actually find a workaround that also works on windows: `exec "nim c readme.nim"; "README.md".writeFile(staticExec("readme"))`. Do you want to add it to your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: In this case, it's better that you write your own answer and accept it. It's encouraged by StackOverflow rules (it has its own medal and all: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner)